# Cloudfoundry Eclipse plugin: Cannot see in Servers

Tags: eclipse, cloud-foundry

After updating to CloudFoundry 1.2.0 with Eclipse Indigo, I can't see any VMWare server in the New Server definition of Eclipse.
Is this a bug or I must configure something?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check it in Help->About->Installation Details->Installed Software? If it is there you might want to have a fresh eclipse build and reinstall. It works fine in my eclipse.

Comment: I've got the Cloud Foundry Integration plugin installed in both Indigo and Juno and the Servers view shows up OK. I did try removing, restarting, and reinstalling the plugin on Juno just to check.

Comment: Yes I see in my installed software. I tried also to reinstall, restart and so on but no success.

Comment: I saw this in someone else's Eclipse installation. He had a large number of other servers configured. Do you have the same?

Comment: If it is possible can you try SpringSource Tool Suite, aka STS. It is a customised version of eclipse by Spring. Many web app essential frameworks/components are shipped within the binary downloaded. Try install the cf plugin to STS.

Answer (score 1):

Just did an eclipse juno J2EE update on 22oct2012 and this fixed the missing VMWare vFabric tc Server without needing to reinstall the VMWare component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your JDK to JDK7, it works for me when I update my JDK6 to JDK7